# Angular Calendar from mattlewis92/angular-calendar show events by users list in Week/Month View

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

I have implemented angular-calendar from (https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar) in my angular project and it works fine, now I'm trying to show events by users list in the Week and month View. I'm trying to show something like this:

**Week view**:

|  | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | Ev1 |  |  |  | EV2 |  |  |
| User 2 | Ev1 |  |  | EV2 |  |  |  |
| User 3 |  | EV1 | EV2 |  | EV3 |  |  |

**Month view**:

```
       |  1  |  2  |  3   | 4   |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10  | 11  | 12  | 13  | 14  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       | Mon | Tue |  Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun | Mon | Tue |  Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun | ......
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
User 1 | Ev1 |     |      |     | EV2 |     |     |     | Ev3 |     |  EV4 |     |     |     | .....
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
User 2 | Ev1 |     |      | EV2 |     |     |     |  Ev3   |  |     |      | EV4 |     |     | .....
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
User 3 |     | EV1|  EV2  |     | EV3 |     |     |     | Ev4 |     | EV5  |     |     |     | .....
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I searched in the documentation (https://angular-calendar.com/docs/) but I didn't find any thing that can help me to achieve this.

Comment: Hey James, I'm having the same need here, and I want to know if you found a solution please.

Comment: hello unfortunately no you have to ask directly https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar i did that before but i didn't get the rigth answer